# Multiple images in media for Pinterest button

Tags: wordpress, button, pinterest

Is it possible to include multiple images in the media parameter for a Custom Pinterest button?

For instance, I know ow to include one specific image:

```
<?php $pinterestimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&media=<?php echo $pinterestimage[0]; ?>&description=<?php the_title(); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="vertical">Pin It</a>
```

but let's say I have a image carousel in a custom post type. I want the ability to pin each image in the carousel. I have already queried the images for the carousel, so it's just a matter of the syntax of encoding them into the url properly. This didn't work:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/../../?url=<?php echo urlenco../&
media=<?php echo $largeImages; ?>&../../>Pin It</a>
```

where $largeImages is a query of all attachments in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. It's quite simple, but not explicitly stated in the docs. Just remove the media tag altogether and it will pull images from the post.

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&description=<?php the_title(); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="vertical"><span><img width="29" height="29" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/socialButtons/share/icons/24/pinterest.png" alt="Twitter" /></span></a>
```

Comment: How to add multiple media images in parameter?

Comment: but its not getting exact images from that URL. They are suggesting extra images also. I think so it will be better if we can pass multiple images in media. I have tried but it didnt work.